Why is the raydium API swap code so problematic
Currently i am using the following code to perform swaps on raydium: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/blob/master/src/api/swap.ts
However often it returns the error: TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError. After forcing it to retry a few times I get a successful transaction which takes about 10 minutes overall.
My current setup is to use the high fee and multiply it by 1.5 to get an even higher fee. I am swapping 0.001 SOL for RAY and slippage is 1%.

This question is similar to: How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
